# Is there a better way to distinguish between no children or invalid parent identfiier?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to retrieve all children for a given parent. There are three cases to be distinguished:

- There are children, return them in a JSON array.
- There are no children but the parent exists, return an empty JSON array.
- The parent does not exist, do not return anything.

Getting the children is quite easy:

```
select json_agg(child)
from   child
where  child.parent_id = :parent_id
```

A problem with `json_agg` is that it always returns `null` when there are no rows. So the following will return one row with value `null` instead of `0` rows:

```
select json_agg(child)
from   child
where  false
```

This adds a complexity to distinguish between the three cases. To work around this, I came up with the following:

```
with
parent as
(
    select id
    from   parent
    where  id = :parent_id
),
result as
(
    select     coalesce(json_agg(child), '[]')
    from       child
    inner join parent
    on         child.parent_id = parent.id
)
select result.*
from   result
where  exists(select * from parent)
```

This seems to work, but it is rather clumsy. I am wondering if there is a better solution. Any ideas?

**update**

As request, this is want I want:

- `[{...}, {...}, ...]` when there are children.
- `[]` when there are no children but the parent exists.
- `no rows` when the parent does not exist.

Comment: `HAVING json_agg(child) IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I need to distinguish between the 3 cases. Adding `having json_agg(child) is not null` would not allow me to distinguish the `the parent exists but there are no children currently` case, if I am right?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the expected output. Is that enough information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` with an aggregate in a derived table, e.g.:

```
select children
from (
    select p.id, case when min(c.id) is null then '[]'::json else json_agg(c) end as children
    from parent p
    left join child c on c.parent_id = p.id
    group by p.id
    ) s
where id = :parent_id
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you do `min(c.id)`?

Comment: It just checks if there are any children (note, he's also grouped by `parent.id` and can't check `c.id` whithout an aggregate around it...)  *(though it appears to just have the same effect as `COALESCE(json_agg(c), '[]'::json)`)*

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks, interesting approach.

Comment: @KevinDeGrote - I cannot use `c.id` because of `group by`. This can be any simple aggregate.

Comment: @MatBailie - `COALESCE(json_agg(null), '[]'::json)` gives `[null]`, my query yields `[]`.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but: isn't it better to do `id = :parent_id` in the inner query, instead of the outer/root query? Or will the planner always be smart to move that predicate downwards?

Comment: @KevinDeGrote The planner will effectively use "macro like expansion" to propagate the condition through to the inner query.  *(Imagine the inner query to be a view, as sub-queries are also known as inline-views, the planner can easily be understood to handle the view, so...)*

Comment: That's good news. Because, without such logic, we are first computing the children for all parents, and then finally just selecting one single parent from this pool. I am not really an expert in SQL, as you might have noticed :)

Comment: Without such logic, SQL would suck donkey balls.  *(More seriously, SQL is a "declarative" language rather than an "imperative" language that most people are familiar with.  This means that the optimiser/planner/whatever-term-you-like can choose any way it sees fit to solve the problem you have declared.  This gives it a lot of scope "to be clever for you".)*

Comment: @KevinDeGrote - when in doubt use `explain analyse` to both queries, the plan will be the same. If `min(c) is null` seems to hacky, you can use `count(c) = 0` this may be more intuitive. 
 
@MatBailie - thanks for valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour for aggregate functions, you just have an implicit `GROUP BY <everything down to one row>`.  So, use the aggregate version of a WHERE clause *('HAVING')*?

In there you can check for `NULL`, and/or the existence of a parent.

```
select COALESCE(json_agg(child), '[]')   AS json_object
from   child
where  child.parent_id = :parent_id
HAVING json_agg(child) IS NOT NULL
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM parent WHERE id = :parent_id)
```

Or, to be a little bit DRY but more verbose...

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(json_object, '[]'::json)  AS json_object
FROM
(
  select json_agg(child)  AS json_object
  from   child
  where  child.parent_id = :parent_id
)
  your_query
WHERE
  json_object IS NOT NULL
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM parent WHERE id = :parent_id)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It's only a pitty we have to repeat `json_agg(child)`.

Comment: That's basically my initial query :).

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas!

Comment: @KevinDeGrote - I personally think Klin's answer is better than mine.  The cost of the `LEFT JOIN` is the same as the `EXISTS`, it's more rigorous with the `CASE` instead of `COALESCE()`, only has the `:parent_id` parameter once...

Comment: I changed my answer. I was confused by the `min(c.id)`. Now I understand it, but isn't it a rather a hack?

Comment: It's "awkward", but not a hack in my opinion.  Would `COUNT(c.id) > 0` feel better to you?

Comment: Makes sense... `count(c.id) = 0` feels indeed more right, but I guess I am being pedantic here.